# Parse.com File storage creating JSON with key:property - "__type":"File"

Tags: json, file, parse-platform, types

After downloading a parse Class, I found that it stores file type column as:

```
{ "results": [
{
    "createdAt": "2015-10-27T15:06:37.324Z",
    "file": {
        "__type": "File",
        "name": "uniqueidentifier1-filename.ext",
        "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/example-file-url.png"
    },
    "objectId": "8eBlOHHchQ",
    "updatedAt": "2015-10-27T15:06:37.324Z"
},
{
    "createdAt": "2015-10-27T14:35:02.853Z",
    "file": {
        "__type": "File",
        "name": "uniqueidentifier2-filename.ext",
        "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/example-file-url.png"
    },
    "objectId": "B2tg7tBsHL",
    "updatedAt": "2015-10-27T14:35:02.853Z"
}] }
```

For an app, I need to locally construct a JSON class like this and then manually upload it to the parse app. So I save the file first to parse and the get the file name and file url by file.url() and file.name() and then construct an object like this:

```
object.file.name = file.name();
object.file.url = file.url();
```

This works fine and sets the url and name keys as expected. However, after this if I do

```
object.file['__type'] = 'file'
```

the object.file object get converted into some weird parse file object and console.log(object) gives (notice the extra underscore and no __type key)

```
file: b.File
   _name: "uniqueidentifier1-filename.ext"
   _url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/example-file-url.png"
```

but console.log(object.file) gives properly

```
Object {url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/example-file-url.png", name: "uniqueidentifier1-filename.ext", __type: "File"}
```

saving the object in a text file also gives the same result as console.log(object). However, I want the text file to be similar to how parse actually stores it so that I can then upload the text file to a parse class.

Comment: What is your App on ? iOS, Android or web ?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, call the `toJSON()` function on your PFObject which returns a JSON object suitable for saving on Parse.